# Strange behaviour of Append

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have the following situation and I completely do not understand why the second system can be solved but the first (of the same equations, as it seems) cannot.
How is it possible?

```
In[1]:= a={x^2+y^2==1};
Append[a,x+y==0]
Solve[a,{x,y}]

b={x^2+y^2==1,x+y==0}
Solve[b,{x,y}]

Out[2]= {x^2+y^2==1,x+y==0}
During evaluation of In[1]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[3]= {{y->-Sqrt[1-x^2]},{y->Sqrt[1-x^2]}}
Out[4]= {x^2+y^2==1,x+y==0}
Out[5]= {{x->-(1/Sqrt[2]),y->1/Sqrt[2]},{x->1/Sqrt[2],y->-(1/Sqrt[2])}}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `AppendTo[a,x+y==0]`? ...because simply using `Append` does not modify `a`

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G Thank you! So that is just a consequence of my poor knowledge of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Append` has no side effect

You may try `AppendTo`

```
a = {x^2 + y^2 == 1};
AppendTo[a, x + y == 0]
Solve[a, {x, y}]
```

resulting in

```
 (* {{x -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), y -> 1/Sqrt[2]}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[2], 
      y -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}} *)
```

or consider simply

```
Append[a, x + y == 0] // Solve
```

Comment: `a=Append[a,x+y==0]` also would work.