# Append[] is not working for empty list

Tags: vector, list-manipulation

I am trying to create an empty list and add an element but the list is not being populated.

**My code**

```
configsPermTerms = List[]; Append[configsPermTerms, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0}, 8}] Length[configsPermTerms] configsPermTerms
```

Output

```
{{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 8}}
0
{}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for `AppendTo`?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/29734) on the pitfalls post.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79859/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the difference between

```
Append
```

and

```
AppendTo
```

Append doesn't reassign the value of the List, while AppendTo does.