# Why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: infinite-loop

The following minimal non working example is an infinite loop: why is it so?

```
list={1};
n=2;
While[Last@list<10,Append[list,n];n++]
```

It seems that `Append` does not append the last value to list so `While` is always `True`, but why is it so?

Comment: You're confusing Append and AppendTo. Please look them up.

Comment: @Szabolcs would you object to me re-marking this as a duplicate of [(112183)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112183/121)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop is infinite, because the result of [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) is the new list, not the modification of existing.

Documentation:

> ```
> Append[expr,elem]
>   gives expr with elem appended.
> ```

And:

> ```
> AppendTo[s,elem]
>   appends elem to the value of s, and resets s to the result.
> ```

So, you either need to reassign the value of [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) or use [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html):

```
list={1};
n=2;
While[Last@list<10,list=Append[list,n];n++]
```

Or:

```
list={1};
n=2;
While[Last@list<10,AppendTo[list,n];n++]
```

Both will yield the same result.